# Emulator process termination - The Android emulator exited with code -11 after startup

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, archlinux

When I started the Android emulator in code on Arch Linux, the emulator crashed and showed an error message in the terminal.

Failed to launch Pixel 7 API 34: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds.

Registration information is provided below:

```
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -11 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /home/guilherme/.android/avd/../avd/Pixel_7_API_34.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
[ERR] Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.162798   43099 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
[ERR] added library libvulkan.so
[ERR] initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472911   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1225] Initializing VkEmulation features:
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472928   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1226]     glInteropSupported: false
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472932   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1227]     useDeferredCommands: true
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472936   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1229]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472939   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1230]     useVulkanComposition: false
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472943   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1231]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472946   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1232]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472950   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1233]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472955   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1234]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472960   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1235]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472962   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1236]     guestUsesAngle: false
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.472965   43099 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1237]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.473133   43099 FrameBuffer.cpp:486] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Mesa)
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.473138   43099 FrameBuffer.cpp:487] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (llvmpipe (LLVM 16.0.6, 256 bits))
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.473141   43099 FrameBuffer.cpp:488] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0.1-arch1.1)
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.473144   43099 FrameBuffer.cpp:489] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.473151   43099 FrameBuffer.cpp:490] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
[ERR] WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
[ERR] WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.603932   43220 FrameBuffer.cpp:3682] setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2400 dpiX 420 dpiY 420
[ERR] I0229 14:30:18.603961   43220 FrameBuffer.cpp:3695] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
[ERR] WARNING | Device 'cache' does not have the requested snapshot 'default_boot'
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'
[ERR] qemu-system-x86_64: Unable to connect character device modem: address resolution failed for ::1:34553: Name or service not known
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.071941:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.072100:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.072444:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.072525:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.072606:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.074903:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.074958:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.075011:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.075061:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.075121:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.075174:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.075226:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43103:20240229,143028.075279:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[ERR] [43103:43104:20240229,143028.098097:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir /tmp/android-guilherme/emu-crash-33.1.24.db/attachments/3a3ccca3-368d-410f-9f8e-3bd89736c21f: No such file or directory (2)
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.
```

What I have already tried to do to resolve this error is to delete Android Studio and the AVD and SDK files and install again.

But it doesn't resolve the error.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but couldn't find a fix. However, if you could share your hardware and disto specs that could help. At least we could know if we have something in common. Thanks.